# How can I split a file by pattern on GNU linux? (split command does not have a -p flag on GNU as it does on BSD)

Tags: linux, split, gnu

Background: I have a very large .sql file, which causes a timeout when I import it into my MySQL server. To fix this in Mac OS X, i run: `split -p 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS' my-backup-file.sql` which causes a series of smaller files which then don't cause the timeout.

My issue is:

- `split -p 'pattern' my-backup-file.sql` works fine on Mac OS but not on GNU linux such as Ubuntu as far as I understand.
- I cannot run something like `docker run -v $(pwd):/workspace some/freebsdimage /bin/bash -c 'cd /workspace && split -p pattern my-backup-file.sql' because I can't run a freebsd docker image on a non-freebsd docker host.

What alternative is there in Ubuntu to split a file into smaller files every time a pattern occurs?

Comment: Mac OSX is Unix, not BSD, but has some user components of BSD. By far and away "Mac OS" is also not "BSD linux" as if such a thing really existed at all.

Comment: Try `csplit -k inputfile '/pattern/' '{99999}'`

Comment: Thanks @Rob, I edited my question.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick thanks, that's the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The answer which works for me, as @Mark Plotnick states above, is

```
csplit -k inputfile '/pattern/' '{99999}'
```